# PDFKit background search

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I'm trying to run a search on a background thread using new iOS PDFKit framework.

```
override func main() {
    if isCancelled {
      return
    }
    pdfDocument = PDFDocument.init(url: book.document.url)!
    pdfDocument.delegate = self
    pdfDocument.beginFindString("test", withOptions: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) (async)
    //pdfDocument.findString("test", withOptions: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive]) (sync)

  }
```

The problem is that none of the PDFDocumentDelegate's methods isn't called and if I use the TIME Profiler nothing seems to happen. 
**The sync option works but cannot be cancelled**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Delegate methods will work fine for synchronous `findString`.

In case of async `beginFindString` you should rely on notifications:

```
// Objective - C
PDFDocumentDidBeginFindNotification
PDFDocumentDidEndFindNotification
PDFDocumentDidBeginPageFindNotification
PDFDocumentDidEndPageFindNotification
PDFDocumentDidFindMatchNotification
```

or

```
// Swift
Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidBeginFind
Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidEndFind
Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidBeginPageFind
Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidEndPageFind
Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidFindMatch
```

Comment: The problem is that `beginFindString` does nothing on a background thread, only `func documentDidBeginDocumentFind(_ notification: Notification)` is called. On main thread everything works ok. My guess is that async search has a thread guard. I tried with delegate and notifications as well.

Comment: Yep. It appears as though the async aspect of beginFindString: simply doesn't work. I noticed this was a problem when I started testing very large PDFs. Since beginFindString: runs on the main queue by default, and fails to invoke notifications if explicitly but on a different queue, this method is worthless.