# Why are the results of PDFKit .beginFindStrings nil?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

Self-teaching novice here.

**My end goal:**

iOS/Mac app that loads a directory of PDFs, searches each for an array of strings, and lists which PDFs contain which strings where.

**Problem in prototyping for only one PDF:**

I receive a perplexing nil from loading a chosen PDF, running `.beginFindStrings(["and", "the"], withOptions: .caseInsensitive)` and waiting for the Notification `.PDFDocumentDidEndFind` to check `[PDFSelection]` .

That shouldn't be. Memory shows the PDF is loaded. Am I doing something wrong with threads? I think I've followed the `async` advice here: [PDFKit background search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584298/pdfkit-background-search/46676497#46676497)

**Code**

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    var matchesFound: PDFSelection?

    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func importPDF(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard urls.count == 1 else {return}
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urls[0])
        let subjectPDF = PDFDocument.init(data: data)
        guard subjectPDF!.isLocked == false else {return}

        subjectPDF!.beginFindStrings(["the", "and"], withOptions: .caseInsensitive)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidFindMatch(_:)), name: Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidEndFind, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func onDidFindMatch(_ notification: Notification) {
        resultsLabel.text = "\(String(describing: matchesFound?.string))"
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**Code with Markup**

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentPickerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

//Array of PDFSelection search results
    var matchesFound: PDFSelection?

//Temporary display for search result strings
    @IBOutlet weak var resultsLabel: UILabel!

//Choose a PDF to import, temporarily limited to one
    @IBAction func importPDF(_ sender: Any) {
        let picker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String], in: .import)
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        self.present(picker, animated: true)
    }

//Load the picked PDF as subjectPDF, if unlocked
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
        guard urls.count == 1 else {return}
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urls[0])
        let subjectPDF = PDFDocument.init(data: data)
        guard subjectPDF!.isLocked == false else {return}

//Find temporary array of strings
        subjectPDF!.beginFindStrings(["the", "and"], withOptions: .caseInsensitive)

//Trigger results readout upon search competion
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidFindMatch(_:)), name: Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidEndFind, object: nil)
    }

//Readout found strings to temporary label
    @objc func onDidFindMatch(_ notification: Notification) {
        resultsLabel.text = "\(String(describing: matchesFound?.string))"
    }

    func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked 7 months ago though, I hope you already found the solution.
Anyway the solution for your problem:

**1-** Move the line below to the `viewDidLoad()`, because you are adding an observer after triggering the `beginFindString()` method.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidFindMatch(_:)), name: Notification.Name.PDFDocumentDidEndFind, object: nil)
```

**2-** You are never assigning any value to `matchesFound` variable, so it's always nil.

**3-** To get the matches from `beginFindString` method, you need to add an observer for `PDFDocumentDidFindMatch` and get the data from `userInfo` instead of `PDFDocumentDidEndFind`.
`PDFDocumentDidEndFind` observer will be called when searching has been finished, you can use this observer for removing you loading view for instance.

Here is a sample code of the correct implementation:

```
var matchesFound = [PDFSelection]()

// MARK: Life cycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didFindMatch(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.PDFDocumentDidFindMatch, object: nil)
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

// This method will get called every-time a match has been found.
@objc private func didFindMatch(_ sender: Notification) {
    guard let selection = sender.userInfo?["PDFDocumentFoundSelection"] as? PDFSelection else { return }

    self.matchesFound.append(selection)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for rounding back to an old question. I ended up just converting the thing to text and that worked much easier for my purpose of querying it for strings in proximity to each other.